# Gitlab CI copy/move file

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

Is it possible to copy or move a file to a different location in my .yml script?

I am generating a dependency diagram (as a svg) and would like this to be moved after it is created to an other location (the folder of the documentation).

Comment: Can you add more details to your question such as `gitlab-ci.yml` or whatever you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can direct run bash command in ci.yml:

```
before_script:
  - echo "start CI"
  - ls -al
  - mv file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

GitLab-ci.yml

```
script:
    - mv index.html ./public
```

Here is the "index.html" move to the public directory.